# Question about power mirror motor ( Dorman 924-5204) connector

Tags: connector, wing-mirrors

I need to use a power mirror motor ( Dorman 924-5204) for a non automotive application and need your help to find a connector which will plug into the four wire connector on the mirror motor. Will appreciate any help you can provide !  Connector pics attached. 
[image: Dorman 924-5204 power mirror motor connector]

Comment: If you have access to the car it came from, or find it in a scrap yard , get one from there.

Comment: Well according to google the part fits a 2008-2011 Freightliner Cascadia. So if you wanted a connector you would have to find a junk one or call a dealership. You could probably find female terminals that fit those and make something for that though.